# When Query returns Null (no objects) how to display "nothing found" in django template?

Tags: python, django

I'm using chain method for querying the database something like,

```
objects = chain(Data.objects.filter(q_obj)..... )
```

In template,

```
{% for obj in objects %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

But, if objects returns No data then how can I print out "Nothing found".

I tried all of these,

> {% if objects == " " %}
>
> {% for obj in objects %}
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> {% endfor %}
>
> {% else %}
>
> Nothing found
>
> {% endif %}

Also I tried,

> if objects == None
>
> if objects is null
>
> if objects|default_if_none:""
>
> if not objects
>
> if objects|length > 0

But couldn't make that happen.

Comment: check your model may probelm

Comment: objects should be this format other wise wrong yours ,objects = {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139} this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% for object in objects %}
   ...
{% empty %}
   nothing found
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: WOW, Working Perfectly Fine. Thank You very much Sir :)